# Wordpress Debugging to solve errors?

Tags: wordpress

I work on wordpress demo then i faced this problem

```
There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.
```

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.

How can debug wordpress demo??

Answer (score 0):

To debug wordpress open your wp-config.php file and set wp_debug to true and check in browser